# Vector triple product question

Tags: vector-spaces

Prove that the vector **p** = **b**( **a** $\cdot $**c**)-**c**( **a**$ \cdot $**b**) is orthogonal to the vector **a**.

I know: **a**$ \cdot $**b** =0 <=> **a** and **b** are orthogonal.

I tried applying this to this question, and I ended up with: (Note all terms are vectors, it takes too long to put the bold on for every term!)

b $ \cdot $a(a$ \cdot $c)-c$ \cdot $a(a$ \cdot $b)

But I am unsure how  to progress?

Comment: not sure why the preview looks different to the actual thing???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dot prodcuts are symmetric.  $a \cdot b = b \cdot a$.

So you have

$$a \cdot p = (a \cdot b) (a \cdot c) - (a \cdot c) (a \cdot b)$$

All these dot products are numbers (scalars), so you could set $a \cdot b = x$ and $a \cdot c = y$ and you'd have

$$a \cdot p = xy - yx = 0$$

which implies $a \perp p$.